# How to get cut needed value in to different col in python dataframe？

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a data frame like follow:

```
   pop    state  value1       value2
0  1.8    Ohio   2000001      2100345
1  1.9    Ohio   2001001      1000524
2  3.9  Nevada   2002100      1000242
3  2.9  Nevada   2001003      1234567
4  2.0  Nevada   2002004      1420000
```

And I have a ordered dictionary like following:

```
OrderedDict([(1, OrderedDict([('value1_1', [1, 2]),('value1_2', [3, 4]),('value1_3',[5,7])])),(1, OrderedDict([('value2_1', [1, 1]),('value2_2', [2, 5]),('value2_3',[6,7])]))])
```

I want to changed the data frame as the OrderedDict needed.

```
 pop  state  value1_1 value1_2  value1_3  value2_1 value2_2 value2_3    
0  1.8  Ohio     20     0          1        2       1003     45
1  1.9  Ohio     20     1          1        1         5      24
2  3.9  Nevada   20     2         100       1         2      42
3  2.9  Nevada   20     1          3        1       2345     67
4  2.0  Nevada   20     2          4        1       4200     0
```

I think it is really a complex logic in python pandas. How can I solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, your `OrderedDict` overwrites the same key, you need to use different keys.

```
d= OrderedDict([(1, OrderedDict([('value1_1', [1, 2]),('value1_2', [3, 4]),('value1_3',[5,7])])),(2, OrderedDict([('value2_1', [1, 1]),('value2_2', [2, 5]),('value2_3',[6,7])]))])
```

Now, for your actual problem, you can iterate through `d` to get the items, and use the `apply` function on the DataFrame to get what you need.

```
for k,v in d.items():
    for k1,v1 in v.items():
        if k == 1:
            df[k1] = df.value1.apply(lambda x : int(str(x)[v1[0]-1:v1[1]]))
        else:
            df[k1] = df.value2.apply(lambda x : int(str(x)[v1[0]-1:v1[1]]))
```

Now, df is

```
   pop   state   value1   value2  value1_1  value1_2  value1_3  value2_1  \
0  1.8    Ohio  2000001  2100345        20         0         1         2
1  1.9    Ohio  2001001  1000524        20         1         1         1
2  3.9  Nevada  2002100  1000242        20         2       100         1
3  2.9  Nevada  2001003  1234567        20         1         3         1
4  2.0  Nevada  2002004  1420000        20         2         4         1

   value2_2  value2_3
0      1003        45
1         5        24
2         2        42
3      2345        67
4      4200         0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this would point you in the right direction.

Converting the `value1` and `value2` columns to `string` type:

```
df['value1'], df['value2'] = df['value1'].astype(str), df['value2'].astype(str)


dct_1,dct_2 = OrderedDict([('value1_1', [1, 2]),('value1_2', [3, 4]),('value1_3',[5,7])]), 
              OrderedDict([('value2_1', [1, 1]),('value2_2', [2, 5]),('value2_3',[6,7])])
```

Converting `Ordered Dictionary` to a list of tuples:

```
dct_1_list, dct_2_list = list(dct_1.items()), list(dct_2.items())
```

Flattening a list of lists to a single list:

```
L1, L2 = sum(list(x[1] for x in dct_1_list), []), sum(list(x[1] for x in dct_2_list), [])
```

Subtracting the even slices of the `list` by 1 as the string indices start from 0 and not 1:

```
L1[::2], L2[::2] = np.array(L1[0::2]) - np.array([1]), np.array(L2[0::2]) - np.array([1])
```

Taking the appropriate slice positions and mapping those values to the newly created columns of the `dataframe`:

```
df['value1_1'],df['value1_2'],df['value1_3']= map(df['value1'].str.slice,L1[::2],L1[1::2])
df['value2_1'],df['value2_2'],df['value2_3']= map(df['value2'].str.slice,L2[::2],L2[1::2])
```

Dropping off unwanted columns:

```
df.drop(['value1', 'value2'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Final result:

```
print(df)

   pop   state value1_1 value1_2 value1_3 value2_1 value2_2 value2_3
0  1.8    Ohio       20       00      001        2     1003       45
1  1.9    Ohio       20       01      001        1     0005       24
2  3.9  Nevada       20       02      100        1     0002       42
3  2.9  Nevada       20       01      003        1     2345       67
4  2.0  Nevada       20       02      004        1     4200       00
```